# Basic CRUD UI Spring

Tags: java, spring, crud, vaadin4spring

Could someone please point me to a basic crud webapplication framework using Java/Spring frameworks. I am looking for a design something like this.

[image: UI For the crud operation]

It needs to list the entries. Add a new entry. Filter the listed out entries based on some custom fields etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use http://jhipster.github.io/

It has lot of options to choose for server as well as client side technologies. You just need to give details of your entities and it will create a nice crud application with awesome UI.

Have a look at some sample screens at https://www.drissamri.be/blog/technology/starting-modern-java-project-with-jhipster/